# Using Named URL in blade template

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

In Django, I can do this:

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Account Link</a>
```

which would give me `domain/account/login` where I have that URL named in my urls.py

```
url(r'^account/login/$', views.Login.as_view(), name='account_login'),
```

I want to do something similar in Laravel 5.2

I currently have something like this:

```
Route::get('/survey/new', ['as' => 'new.survey', 'uses' => 'SurveyController@new_survey']);
```

How do I use in my template, plus passing in parameters?

I came across this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers, but it was just a piece of a white page without relevant content of how to actually use it.

Comment: `route('new.survey');`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the `route()` helper, documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route).

```
<a href="{{ route('new.survey') }}">My Link</a>
```

If you include `laravelcollective/html` you could use `link_to_route()`. This was originally part of the core but removed in Laravel 5. It's explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0)

```
{!! link_to_route('new.survey', 'My Link') !!}
```

The Laravel Collective have documented the aforementioned helper [here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#generating-urls). The function prototype is as follows

```
link_to_route($routeName, $title = null, $parameters = [], $attributes = []);
```

If for example you wanted to use parameters, it accepts an array of key value pairs which correspond to the named segments in your route URI.

For example, if you had a route

```
Route::get('surveys/{id}', 'SurveyController@details')->name('detail.survey');
```

You can generate a link to this route using the following in the parameters.

```
['id' => $id]
```

A full example, echoing markup containing an anchor to the named route.

```
{!! link_to_route('new.survey', 'My Link', ['id' => $id]) !!}
```

Comment: You know, what you wrote ain't helping. You just posted exactly what is on the docs site. My question is, in my template with a url like this: `<a href="What-do-I-Put-In-Here">My Link</a>` to get the link generated for me. All what you posted above doesn't do that, does it?

Comment: You didn't explicitly ask for how to generate markup; and without knowledge of django `url` would suggest you generate a url to the route, not markup. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I ended the question by saying: `How do I use in my template, plus passing in parameters?` - How will I be able to use in template without it generating a markup, unless that's possible in Laravel.

Comment: You can use a URL in a template just as you can use a URL within an anchor's href attribute in a template. There's a difference between a URL and markup containing the URL; both of which can be output in a template. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: So, if I want to use the `link_to_route()` with params, it'll be something like this? `{{ link_to_route('detail.survey', 'The Title', [$survey->id]) }}` <- this gives me error. Will appreciate your help regarding appending a param. The docs don't mean anything to me since the docs don't make any sense.

Comment: What error do you get? You'll need to use `{!! !!}` to prevent the markup being double escaped if you use `link_to_route()`. See [Other Control Structures: Displaying Raw Text With Curly Braces](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures). If I remember rightly the params are key value pairs. I.e. if your route is like `surveys/{id}` the parameters would be `['id' => $survey->id]`

Comment: Got it, Thanks! You may perhaps wanna add the params example to your answer above. Thanks for the clarification. Useful! Shame on Laravel docs

Comment: No worries. I've updated the answer with the clarification.