# how to make working menu tab with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel 5.4
I have created a menu, in which three tabs Home, about and contact. When I click on Home then it should be on home page. When click on about, it should be on about page....

**web.php:**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
return View('method1.home');
});
Route::get('about', function()
{
return View('method1.about');
});
```

**method1 is folder in resources\views**

**home.blade.php:**

```
@extends('method1.dashboard')
@section('content')
 <h1>This is home page</h1>
@endsection
```

**about.blade.php is:**

```
@extends('method1.dashboard')
@section('content')
 <h1>This is about page</h1>
@endsection
```

**dashboard.blade.php is:**

```
@include('method1.includes.menu-header')
```

**menu-header.blade.php is:**

```
<li class="active"> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="/about">About</a></li>
```

But when I click on home or about page. It shows Page is not found.

My laravel projet folder name is **admin_laravel**. When I run http://localhost/admin_laravel/ then it shows home page and when run http://localhost/admin_laravel/about it shows about page.

But when I click on **about menu button** then in browser shows link **http://localhost/about**. Means it is not going with **http://localhost/admin_laravel/about** and page is not showing.

Comment: `<a href="/about">` You are explicitly linking to the about page in your root

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Named URL in blade template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837987/using-named-url-in-blade-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something there, For a quick fix you can do this:

```
<li class="active"> <a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="{{ url('about') }}">About</a></li>
```

You can also give route name and go with route method:

```
Route::get('about', function()
{
   return View('method1.about');
})->name('about');
```

Then:

```
<li> <a href="{{ route('about') }}">About</a></li>
```

Here is the details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route

Answer (score 2):

You're hard-coding your URLs. When you have `<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>` you're telling your browser to go to the `about` path from the root of the domain (which is what happens when you prefix your URL with `/`), which in this case is `http://localhost/`.

There's a few things you should be doing. First, set the base URL for your project, you can update `APP_URL` in your *.env* file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/admin_laravel
```

or the `url` option in *config/app.php*.

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/admin_laravel'),
```

Secondly, when generating URLs in Laravel there are quite a few options. If you're not using named routes, then you should use the `url` helper method to generate your URLs:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('about') }}">About</a></li>
```

That will make sure that your URL is based at the root of your project, rather than the root of the domain. When you use `url` in conjunction with the correct setting as described above, your URLs will be generated correctly.

Comment: url method is working. But APP_URL or 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/admin_laravel'), are not working